# Heroku and GoDaddy DNS configuration

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

I have been struggling to configure my Heroku to point to my domain name registered with GoDaddy.

I've setup my Heroku domain:
[image: herokudns]

And I've configured my CNAME www to point to www.ithhero.com.herokudns.com
[image: dnszonefile]

So far all tutorials/examples I've seen have had a different DNS target e.g. www.ithero.herokuapp.com . And even though I have followed the steps no results have been yielded. Godaddy and Heroku have been bouncing responsibility between them when raising an issue with either.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Hey did you solve this problem ? What did you do ? Can you please explain. I am facing same problem.

Comment: Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKGSGT7mSnQ&t=31s

Answer (score 1):

You postet it a while ago so I assume you found a solution already, but you should only change your CNAME value from:

```
www.ithehero.com.herokudns.com
```

to

```
ithehero.com.herokudns.com
```

Comment: In the Value do i need to give DNS target or Domain name ? Can you please help?

Comment: It should be the DNS target

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an issue on GoDaddy.

If you try the following, you can see that the domain has been setup correctly from Heroku's side:

`curl -v -H "Host: www.ithehero.com" www.ithehero.com.herokudns.com`

Also, if you check your DNS resolution, your CNAME's haven't been propagated at all: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/www.ithehero.com

I would go back to GoDaddy and get them to have a look at this.